# How can i define a Hystrix Client Fallback directly in a @FeignClient

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, netflix-feign

I'm tring to define my fallback function directly in the feign defenition as described in the spring documentation, Please see the code below, but i get an error that i can't define a static class " modifier static not allowed here". How can i get the fallback function to run when feign call fails?

Regards,

Nadav

```
@FeignClient(name = "hello", fallback = HystrixClientFallback.class)

protected interface HystrixClient {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hello")

     Hello iFailSometimes();

}

static class HystrixClientFallback implements HystrixClient {

@Override

public Hello iFailSometimes() {

return new Hello("fallback");

}

}
```

Comment: Move it to a top level class?  `HystrixClientFallback` also needs to be defined as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 9):

Adding `@Component` to the top of the class worked for me.

```
@Component
class HystrixClientFallback implements HystrixClient {

    @Override
    public Hello iFailSometimes() {
        return new Hello("fallback");
    }

}
```